# Switch to Monochrome

Tags: windows, windows-xp, display, colors

Is it possible to switch the display mode under Windows to monochrome somehow? You know, like when you select 'Turn off' in Windows XP and it makes it all grayed out - so I need this but for life.

Comment: it's much easier in Windows 10. Just press Windows+Ctrl+C

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc man this is golden! Please write this comment as an answer and you'll get the well-deserved "Answered" label!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Windows 10 Build 16215 you have the ability to change to monochorome built-in. It's one of the new color filters for ease of access which can be toggled  by <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

> Windows 10 now includes color filters at the system level, including filters designed to make it easier for people with color blindness to differentiate between colors like red and green and to make it easier for people with light sensitivity to create and consume content. You can find these new filtering options under *Settings > Ease of Access > Color and High Contrast* (previously called High Contrast Settings).
>
> https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2017/06/08/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-16215-pc-build-15222-mobile/#C1B2TQQ8YvwdEsjV.97

[image: color filter settings]

[Why did my Windows 10 suddenly turn monochrome?](https://superuser.com/a/1281353/241386)

Answer (score 5):

The **[Color Control Panel Applet for Windows XP](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/confirmation.aspx?id=12714)** is a free add-on from Microsoft (requires a WGA check) that can be used to take advantage of color technology built into Windows XP known as Image Color Management (ICM) 2.0. Once the applet is installed, you can use it to perform the following tasks:

- Install and uninstall color profiles
- Inspect, rename, and compare two different color profiles
- View a 3D graphics plot of color profile gamuts
- Associate color profiles with devices such as printers, monitors, and scanners
- Apply custom color gamut adjustments to one or more displays "on the fly"
- Set up display calibration reminders at intervals you specify

And here's a little tutorial:

**[Manage color on Windows XP with the Color Control Panel Applet](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/solutionbase-manage-color-on-windows-xp-with-the-color-control-panel-applet/)**

Comment: I have to add though, that after doing this (and updating the links in the answer) I couldn't actually get it to preview in monochrome.  I'm sure it should be possible to find a colour profile to fake this, but I failed.

Answer (score 2):

I just discovered this by accident on my Win 7 Pro system

**Hold <kbd>Windows</kbd> Key and tap <kbd>End</kbd> key**

I don't know if this is native to Windows 7 or is a function of some added utility or app.

I was researching that when I stumbled on to this forum question

It is not listed as a documented combo-key entry on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_key

## Update:

ahhaaaa.. I found it. This <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> key combo that activates the monochrome display mode is a new (Nov 2018) feature of the [f.lux utility](https://justgetflux.com/). This utility turns on a blue filter towards bedtime to promote easier sleeping.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a toy that can grey-scale or sepia (or other duo-tone) a Linux desktop (I think it was part of a compbiz demo, bit it was long enough ago for the memory to be hazy) by applying a global filter to the output, so you might be able to find one for Windows too.

As another option, see if your monitor has a colour saturation control - that should do the trick.